# compare two DateTime Objects

Tags: php

actually I have 2 DateTime objects

```
$d1 = new DateTime('04/14/2013 8.00 AM');
$d2 = new DateTime('04/14/2013');
```

so without doing any changes to these 2 objects. is it possible equal these 2 objects.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what is the desired result?

Comment: I need to compare these 2 using only date (04/14/2013) without considering time (8.00 AM)

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference between two DateTime objects, use DateTime::diff() method:

```
$interval = $d1->diff($d2);
```

As a result, you will get a DateInterval object. To get formatted time difference from the DateInterval object, use format() method, for example:

```
echo $interval->format('%s seconds');
```

You can see more examples of comparing DateTime objects [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).
Also check [how to use format() method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the built in diff method for the DateTime objects;

```
$interval = $d1->diff($2);
```

Heres the manual for it: [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Then to get just the days you can format the interval like this

```
$interval = $interval->format('%d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the dates to strip off the time like:

```
if ($d1->format('m/d/Y') == $d2->format('m/d/Y'))
    echo 'equal';
else
    echo 'not equal';
```

or like this:

```
if (date_format($d1, 'm/d/Y') == date_format($d2, 'm/d/Y'))
    echo 'equal';
else
    echo 'not equal';
```

The date_format will put the dates in this format: 04/14/2013

You have to do a date_format on $d2 because it's really '2013-04-14 00:00:00.'